# check if git branch is locked using api on azure devops

Tags: git, azure, tfs, branch, devops

Is there a way to check which branch's are locked by rest api or tf.exe or any client library api?

I try work follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitref and the response not contains the locked/unlocked flag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://{baseUrl}/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/refs?filter=heads/***/master&api-version=6.0
```

- Replace the placeholders with correct details of your repos and give your branch name(heads/***/master) of which you want check it is locked or not.

[image]

- One catch over here, if your branch is not locked then "Islocked" & "Creator" section will not ever get in response.
- To get for all the branches info you can run url without filters
  eg.
  `https://{baseUrl}/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/refs?&api-version=6.0`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right Rest API.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=heads/xxx &api-version=5.0
```

Kindly check your [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#uri-parameters) just make sure you are using the right filter.

There should be **isLocked**  and  **isLockedBy**  info of returned json file.